# Are the two ways of declaring variables the same?

Tags: c#, .net, variable-declaration

Are the two ways of declaring variables shown below the same?

```
int aa= 0, bb= 0, cc= 0, dd= 0;
```

---

```
int aa= 0;
int bb= 0;
int cc= 0;
int dd= 0;
```

Comment: What kind of difference would you expect?

Comment: Yes, they are. Resulting **IL** would be identical. But note, that second variant is much more readable and conventional

Comment: Thanks ..that clears my confusion..

Comment: The question is completely justified, because in VB it's not the same. So i may see where he's coming from.

Comment: @shartelle: It used to be different in VB, but that "gotcha" was fixed I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### YES

C# supports *single statement can assign multiple local variables*

> A single statement can assign multiple local variables. Languages
>   derived from C-style syntax often allow you to use commas to declare
>   multiple variables in one statement. The C# language allows this.

From [`8.5.1 Local variable declarations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664742%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> A local variable declaration that declares multiple variables is
>   equivalent to multiple declarations of single variables with the same
>   type. Furthermore, a variable initializer in a local variable
>   declaration corresponds exactly to an assignment statement that is
>   inserted immediately after the declaration.

First ones `IL` code;

```
 .locals init ([0] int32 aa,
           [1] int32 bb,
           [2] int32 cc,
           [3] int32 dd)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0004:  stloc.1
  IL_0005:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0006:  stloc.2
  IL_0007:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0008:  stloc.3
  IL_0009:  ret
```

Second one `IL` code;

```
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] int32 aa,
           [1] int32 bb,
           [2] int32 cc,
           [3] int32 dd)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0004:  stloc.1
  IL_0005:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0006:  stloc.2
  IL_0007:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0008:  stloc.3
  IL_0009:  ret
```

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, this:

```
int aa = 0, bb = 0, cc, dd;
```

is exactly the same as the following, more common and readable version:

```
int aa = 0;
int bb = 0;
int cc;
int dd;
```

And as [Soner Gönül shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15570830/146622), they produce the same IL code.

But you asked a good question, because things can be more subtle than that.

#### Pointers

In unsafe C# you can work with pointers. A pointer to an integer is written as `int*`. So when you want to declare three variables of type `int*`, you might write this:

```
int* aa, bb, cc;
```

And that correctly represents your intentions:

```
int* aa;
int* bb;
int* cc;
```

However, the syntax for pointers came from the much older language C, and if you declare three pointer variables in C like this:

```
int* aa, bb, cc;
```

Then that means *something subtly different*, and you've actually written:

```
int* aa;
int bb;
int cc;
```

And that's why C developers will write `int *aa` instead, to show that only `aa` is a pointer type, and the rest are normal integers.

```
int *aa, bb, cc;
```

However, I discourage you from writing such a thing in C altogether: it is confusing.

#### Visual Basic and VB.Net

In Visual Basic.NET you can also declare variables on one line:

```vb
Dim aa, bb As Integer
```

And this is the same as:

```vb
Dim aa As Integer
Dim bb As Integer
```

But if you program in Visual Basic (VB.Net's predecessor), then this:

```vb
Dim aa, bb As Integer
```

Means:

```vb
Dim aa As Any     'aa Is Variant
Dim bb As Integer
```

Answer (score 1):

They are the same. I would argue the second option is probably easier to read once your names get a bit more descriptive.